# quit keyboard on bar button tapped swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibarbuttonitem

I have a tableview which has textfields in its cells. I also have a navigation bar at the top. I want to be able to quit editing the textfield (quit the keyboard) when tap on a bar button. I tried using the following codes (showMenu is the name of the bar button):

```
@IBAction func showMenu(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    //self.view.endEditing(true)

    //mainTableView.endUpdates()

    for view in self.view.subviews {

        if let textField = view as? UITextField {

            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}
```

I tried using the commented out codes as well but none of them work. Please help! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `view.endEditing(true)`, so:

```
@IBAction func showMenu(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```